# ImportError: cannot import name 'PY3' from 'torch._six'

Tags: python, pytorch

I am testing ZED Camera with the code on https://github.com/stereolabs/zed-pytorch. While running the final command: python zed_object_detection.py --config-file configs/caffe2/e2e_mask_rcnn_R_50_C4_1x_caffe2.yaml --min-image-size 256

I get the following error:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "zed_object_detection.py", line 6, in 
from predictor import COCODemo
File "/home/fypadmin/Desktop/23Apr_ZED/zed-pytorch/predictor.py", line 4, in 
from torchvision import transforms as T
File "/home/fypadmin/anaconda3/envs/pytorch1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torchvision/**init**.py", line 4, in 
from torchvision import datasets
File "/home/fypadmin/anaconda3/envs/pytorch1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torchvision/datasets/**init**.py", line 1, in 
from .lsun import LSUN, LSUNClass
File "/home/fypadmin/anaconda3/envs/pytorch1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torchvision/datasets/lsun.py", line 19, in 
from .utils import verify_str_arg, iterable_to_str
File "/home/fypadmin/anaconda3/envs/pytorch1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torchvision/datasets/utils.py", line 11, in 
from torch._six import PY3
ImportError: cannot import name 'PY3' from 'torch._six' (/home/fypadmin/anaconda3/envs/pytorch1/lib/python3.8/site-packages/torch/_six.py)

I am new to ML and I am running pytorch 1.8.1. Looking forward to any help. Thanks

Comment: have you by any chance upgraded torch but forgot to upgrade torchvision? or even forgot to install torchvision

Answer (score 16):

For this question, the reason is that your 'torchvision' and 'pytorch' version, they didn't match. So, you need to upgrade your 'torchvision' and 'pytorch' version to the new version

```
pip install --upgrade torch torchvision
```

Comment: This still works :) Thanks

Comment: And do not forget your torchaudio

Answer (score 0):

You need to **downgrade** your torch version to 1.4.x to be compatible. Seeing as https://github.com/stereolabs/zed-pytorch was mostly written a year or two ago, I recommend using python 3.7.x at the latest and downgrading torch.